# How to get the first point's coordinates of a column with type path

Tags: sql, postgresql, path, coordinates, postgis

I have the table above

> ```
> CREATE TABLE public.geometry
> (
>     id          serial not null primary key,
>     distance    float not null,
>     height      float not null,
>     coordinates path not null,
>     gtype       geometrytype not null
> );
> ```

trying to make a query like:

```
SELECT e.id, e.distance, e.height, e.coordinates, e.gtype FROM rf.geometry e WHERE coordinates[0][0] > 10;
```

I got the error:

```
ERROR:  cannot subscript type path because it is not an array
```

Comment: what is the dimension of path?, how you constructed?

Comment: Is there a reason for not using geometry or geography types instead of your custom "path"?